# 1 KEY = AES + PBKDF2 + HMAC

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, hmac, pbkdf2

**My algorithm template this:**

```
...
Mkey = '123' // from Master Key
KdfKey = SHA512(Mkey) // from PBKDF2 password
KdfSalt = SHA256(AesIV + KdfKey) // from PBKDF2 salt
Pbkdf2 = PBKDF2(KdfKey, KdfSalt, 64 + 32) // "64+32"=OutputLen, Iteration is user selected

AesKey = sublast(Pbkdf2, 32) // AES 256 bit CBC key, select last 32 bit
HmacKey = subfirst(Pbkdf2, 64) // HMAC-SHA256 key, select first 64 bit
...
```

**My Questions:**

1. Secure or not secure this ?
2. "HmacKey" crack or founded, security problem for crypted message or "Mkey" ?
3. If this is not secure, how should I use a single password

Comment: "Secure or not secure this?" The answer is ... off-topic, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) article.

Answer (score 0):

> Secure or not secure this ?

Seems you are trying to use the strongest way how to create an encryption and MAC key from a password. I'd say it is a little bit overexagurated, but playing safe it it seems ok

You need to be aware of a weakness in this flow and it is the user input.

> Iteration is user selected

eeee.. see, this is where you should not trust the users (maybe the user could select one of three options, IMHO it makes little sense to rely on users here)

> "HmacKey" crack or founded, security problem for crypted message or "Mkey" ?

if there would be a way to crack/find the hmackey, we have bigger issue than a few passwords. To answer - pbkdf is specifically designed to output uniform distribution from low- entropy passwords, so if the hmackey (output of pbkdf) is found it tells nothing about the original password

> If this is not secure, how should I use a single password

the whole problem with the passwords is they are user-remembered and tend to have low entropy (randomness and length).  using good passwords is the key. (imho using pbkdf is only cryptographic workaround for not having better solution :/ )

Comment: Obviously my intention of using pbkdf2 is not to prevent brute-force. Just use a safer password for HMAC. So for PBKDF2 it can even be an iteration of "5" for me this is trustworthiness. (Yes I'm unsafe for "5 iteration" Brute-force, I'm asking for HMAC)